# Android permission for native files

Tags: android, permissions, native

I have an query regarding Android permission.

If I declare some permission in manifest file then it automatically will impose for native files (C and C++) also?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Android permissions from manifest apply also for code in native library (lib/armeabi/*.so).
Actually for entire application's process.

Comment: @thanks mice ..i have one more question ..is it necessary to add meta-data tag when we use native code in android?